# Can I create a .cert and .key file?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm creating a test server that should use OpenSSL.  I have never made a server so when I read [the apache how-to](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html) I got stuck on the first part; these lines specifically:

> SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www.example.com.cert
>   SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/www.example.com.key

I don't know what to replace "/path/to/www.example.com.cert" and "/path/to/www.example.com.key" with.  I have a completely blank Windows 2003 VM running the server in an isolated test lab so it is completely barren.  As such, when I searched for a .cert file, nothing popped up.

So can I make them?  Keep in mind, I am just testing.  Oh, should be noted, testing OpenSSL on Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use openssl commands to generate keyfile and cert file. My understanding is that yo are trying to create selfsigned certificates.

Basically you have to create your own CA and use ca.cert to sign every keyfile you generate.

Now replace ca.cert at "/path/to/www.example.com.cert" and keyfile with /pahto/key.

Following link explains commands to use for this:

http://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/12/30/howto-make-your-own-cert-with-openssl/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [xca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/). It has already a CA template and https server template in default installation.

First create a CA (new certificate, template CA) and then from this CA (select CA cert and click new certificate) create a Server certificate. Then export CA cert, server cert (www.example.com.cert) and server private key (www.example.com.key).